# sqoop import - job failure between data import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

what will happen incase sqoop fails between large data import job. Will it persist some of the data onto hdfs before the job failure occured ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe import and export works on the similar principles of transactions.

Since Sqoop breaks down export process into multiple transactions, **it is possible that a failed export job may result in partial data being committed to the database**.

This can further lead to subsequent jobs failing due to insert collisions in some cases, or lead to duplicated data in others.

**Solution**
You can overcome this problem by specifying a staging table via the --staging-table option which acts as an auxiliary table that is used to stage exported data. The staged data is finally moved to the destination table in a single transaction.

Comment: But what about import process?